# How do I order by an aggregate count in Rails when also joining to the same table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

There is a scope like this:

```
  scope :sorted_by_dongle_count,
    > { includes(:dongles)
          .order('count(dongles.id) ASC')
          .group('organisations.id')
          .references(:dongles) }
```

This works perfectly well for SQLite, but fails for MySQL.

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Expression #8 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'portal_development.dongles.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by: [query here]

Looking at the query, it is easy to see *why*:

```
SELECT `organisations`.`id` AS t0_r0,
       `organisations`.`name` AS t0_r1,
       `dongles`.`id` AS t1_r0,            This should be an aggregate!
       `dongles`.`name` AS t1_r1,
       `dongles`.`organisation_id` AS t1_r4
FROM `organisations`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `dongles`
    ON `dongles`.`organisation_id` = `organisations`.`id`
GROUP BY organisations.id
ORDER BY count(dongles.id) DESC
```

Is there a proper way to do this without resorting to select() and hard-coding the entire list of columns?

(One other workaround I already know about is count caching. I am considering that already, as having the count readily available would speed up the sorting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I change to:

```
  scope :sorted_by_dongle_count,
   -> { joins(:dongles)       
          .order('count(dongles.id) ASC')
          .group('organisations.id')
          .references(:dongles) }
```

I stop getting the error and the results were the same. So I guess only when using counts or other aggregates, avoid using `includes`? But for all other queries, use `includes`...